# Why do we always assume dices to be distinct entities in possibility problem?

Tags: combinatorics

Going through my SAT practice book, I notice that even when the dices are not specified to be different, we assume that for example, when two dice are thrown (1,6) is different than (6,1). Instead of using $\frac{6^2}{2!}$ to calculate the total number of different results, we use just $6^2$.

Comment: Dice is already plural. The only time you say "dices" is when someone is dicing something. The singular is die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the point of view of determining the sample space, there's no difference between rolling $n$ dice and rolling a single die $n$ times in a row. Both produce the same number of *distinct* outcomes. Once you start looking at specific sets of outcomes, such as counting the number of ways to roll a particular total value, then order may not matter any more.

Comment: So the only time we ignore order is when we are finding the total number of possible outcome?

Comment: If like you said I should imagine two dices being just one due thrown twice, why then isn't (n,n) counted twice? If one is red, and the other green, n on the red one is technically different then n on the green one?

Comment: For the same reason that you wouldn’t count a red 3 plus a green 4 twice. That’s only a single distinguishable outcome. A red 4 plus a green 3, on the other hand, is distinct from red 3 plus green 4